# Use a while loop to read in the entire text file and output a message a list with only the even numbers from the file to the screen

Tags: c#

I can't figure out how to output a message a list with only the even numbers from the file to the screen.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EvenNumbersFile
{
   class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("NumbersFile.txt");
        string line = "";

        while (line != null)
        {

            line = myReader.ReadLine();

            if (line != null)
                Console.WriteLine(line);
        }

        myReader.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What are you not sure about?

Comment: how to output a message a list with even numbers from file to screen?

Comment: That's pretty non-specific. Are you having trouble reading input? Dealing with numbers? Figuring out which is even or odd? What next step are you trying to take that you can't take because you are unsure or confused?

Comment: 1. Set up a program called EvenNumbersFile 
2. Set up a text file called NumbersFile.txt with the following content
3
1
2
4
8
9
13
12
3. Use a while loop to read in the entire text file and output a message a list with only the even numbers from the file to the screen.
that is what i have to do

Comment: You didn't answer my question. We know what the homework assignment is. We need to know what you don't know.

Comment: I am trying to output the even numbers from the list above to the screen

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand what you want now.  You need to parse the number in the file then check to see if it is evenly divisible by two.  Here is some code to try:

```
    while (line != null)
    {

        line = myReader.ReadLine();

        if (line != null)
        {
            int temp;
            if (int.TryParse(line, out temp) && (temp % 2 == 0))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: still not outputting even number :(

Comment: Is it outputting anything? You might have to call Trim() on the line variable to remove whitespace.  Replace the `int.TryParse` with `(int.TryParse(line.Trim(), out temp) && (temp % 2 == 0))`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this sounds like what you need:

```
    while (line != null)
    {
        line = myReader.ReadLine();
        int number = -1;
        if (line != null)
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(line, out number))
            {
                if (number % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(number);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The .TryParse can be omitted if you can guarantee that the input file will only contain numbers.

More complete version:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PrintEvenNumbers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            SafeForWork();
            Console.WriteLine();
            JustShowingOff();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void SafeForWork()
        {
            StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Public\NumbersFile.txt");
            string line = "";

            while (line != null)
            {

                line = myReader.ReadLine();
                int number = -1;
                if (Int32.TryParse(line, out number))
                {
                    if (number % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(number);
                    }
                }
            }

            myReader.Close();
        }

        private static void JustShowingOff()
        {
            List<String> Contents = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\NumbersFile.txt").ToList();
            List<String> Evens = Contents.Where(var => (Int32.Parse(var)) % 2 == 0).ToList();
            Evens.ForEach(var => Console.WriteLine(var));            
        }
    }
}
```

File contents:

1
2
4
13
6
99
8

Comment: 1. Set up a program called EvenNumbersFile 
2. Set up a text file called NumbersFile.txt with the following content
3
1
2
4
8
9
13
12
3. Use a while loop to read in the entire text file and output a message a list with only the even numbers from the file to the screen.